# Visual Studio Debug c++

Tags: debugging, visual-c++

I just installed visual studio and whenever I open already written file .cpp and get up to debug bar, both options of debuging are somehow grey, however when I create one project they awkwardly seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: A single CPP file is not the same as "a project", according to Microsoft. *Everything* must be a project.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to "fast" move .cpp into a new project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open the .cpp file you are opening to read. To compile the file and debug: you'll need to create a project and add the existing .cpp file to the project then you can compile it and debug it.

You can create a project say a temporary project. Whenever you have a cpp file and you want to debug it, open the test project and add the cpp file to the project.

Comment: Hmm, got one more problem. Whenever I open empty project and add already existing file i can debug it and it works, BUT I cant see the code nor edit.... How do I make it appear?

Comment: What do you mean you can't see the code? Does the cpp file appear in the Solution Explorer?

Comment: Through solution explorer it works, was just confused why it didn't show up immediately.